# microsoft azure scheduler custom job

Tags: azure

How do I schedule a job through the Azure dashboard the following way: to run at the top of the hour between 10am-8pm on all days except Monday. If not possible through Dashboard is it possible to Rest API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@4c74356b41 is almost correct.

```
   "recurrence":
   {
        "frequency": "week",
        "interval": 1,
        "schedule":
        {
            "weekDays": ["tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"],
            "hours": [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
            "minutes" : [0]
        }
    }
```

You can also do it in the dashboard, however, it's currently limited to  10 values for "hours". So you will unfortunately have to create two jobs to cover all the hours in your case.

[image]

Comment: odd but I don't see the advanced schedule option in my dashboard.

Comment: @jasan Make sure you select "Weeks" for recurrence. If you still don't see it, please send a screenshot to me at Derek.Li@microsoft.com and I can investigate. Thanks.

Comment: That did it, why the 10 hour limit on each job?

Comment: @jasan, good question. :) Looks like it's just overlooked, we will investigate this today.

Comment: @jasan, I checked and it looks like an arbitrary limit. We will remove it so you can enter max of 24 values for hours and 60 for minutes. Due to year-end holiday, this fix will most likely go out next year. Sorry for the delay, at the moment you should be able to use REST api to workaround this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer to your question is the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-advanced-complexity). Something like this:

```
{
    "weekDays": ["tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"],
    "hours": [10, 20]                      
},
```